# Find all the primes less or equal than N

Tags: c++, algorithm, object-oriented, c++11, unit-testing

This is not a novel interview problem. But I want to address it with the following points:

1. Implement the algorithm with Object-Oriented Design principles in mind.
2. Optimize the solution, if there are many continuous inputs.
3. Write simple unit tests (without using unit testing framework like gtest, boost.test)

Basically, I followed the idea of [Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). To optimize the solution if there are many continuous inputs, I maintain a vector which stores all the primes we have computed so far. If the new `n` is smaller than the previous maximal `n`, we can directly get the primes from "cache" without re-computing the primes again.

I'm specifically looking for suggestions on the algorithm itself, OOD or better unit tests.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class PrimeFinder {
    friend class PrimeFinderTest;
public:
    PrimeFinder(int n = 2) {
        is_prime_.push_back(false);
        is_prime_.push_back(false);
        is_prime_.push_back(true);
        primes_.push_back(2);
        n_ = n;
    }

    vector<int> get_primes(int n) {
        if(n <= n_) {
            return get_primes_subset(n);
        } else {
            extend_primes(n);
            return primes_;
        }
    }

private:
    vector<bool> is_prime_;
    vector<int> primes_;
    int n_;

    vector<int> get_primes_subset(int n) {
        auto iter = primes_.begin();
        while(iter != primes_.end()) {
            if(*iter <= n) ++iter;
            else break;
        }
        return vector<int>(primes_.begin(), iter);
    }

    void extend_primes(int n) {
        is_prime_.reserve(n + 1);
        is_prime_.insert(is_prime_.end(), n - n_, true);

        int bound = sqrt(n);
        for(int i = 2; i <= bound; ++i) {
            if(is_prime_[i]) {
                int j = i + i;
                while(j <= n) {
                    if(j > n_) {
                        is_prime_[j] = false;
                    }
                    j += i;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = n_ + 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            if(is_prime_[i]) primes_.push_back(i);
        }

        n_ = n;
    }
};

template <typename T>
string vec2str(const vector<T>& vec) {
    string str = "";
    for(auto n : vec) {
        str += to_string(n) + " ";
    }
    return str;
}

class PrimeFinderTest {
public:
    void test_get_primes_subset(vector<int> origin, int n) {
        PrimeFinder test;
        test.primes_ = origin;
        vector<int> subset = test.get_primes_subset(n);
        cout << vec2str(subset) << endl;
    }

    void test_extend_primes(vector<int> origin, vector<bool> origin_bool, int n) {
        PrimeFinder test;
        test.primes_ = origin;
        test.is_prime_ = origin_bool;
        test.n_ = test.is_prime_.size() - 1;
        test.extend_primes(n);
        assert(test.n_ == n);
        assert(test.is_prime_.size() == n + 1);
        cout << vec2str(test.primes_) << endl;
    }

    void test_get_primes(int n) {
        PrimeFinder test;
        cout << vec2str(test.get_primes(n)) << endl;
    }

    void test_get_primes_suite(vector<int> nums) {
        PrimeFinder test;
        for(int num : nums) {
            cout << vec2str(test.get_primes(num)) << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    PrimeFinderTest test;
    test.test_get_primes_subset(vector<int>({2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19}),7);
    test.test_get_primes_subset(vector<int>({2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19}),8);
    test.test_get_primes_subset(vector<int>({2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19}),15);

    test.test_extend_primes(vector<int>({2,3,5,7}),
                            vector<bool>({false, false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false}),
                            19);

    test.test_get_primes(2);
    test.test_get_primes(9);
    test.test_get_primes(16);
    test.test_get_primes(30);

    test.test_get_primes_suite(vector<int>({2, 9, 16, 30}));
    test.test_get_primes_suite(vector<int>({16, 9, 2, 30}));
    test.test_get_primes_suite(vector<int>({1,2,3,4,5}));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OO is for simulations and modelling, mathy and algorithmic code is much nicer pure imperative (or functional). Also finding the primes upto n is just `(1..n).select(&:is_prime)` or a sieve if performance is a concern.

Comment: @Quill Thanks for the editing! (and sorry for my poor English expression...). I have added some context and feel free to rephrase them if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Namespaces

[`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1014587). Short code is not a requirement in C++, clear code is preferred.

### Return

`return 0;` is a legacy from C. In C++, it's no longer required to write this manually at the end of `main`. The compiler will take care of returning 'normal' if no errors where thrown or other returns (like `-1`) are encountered.

### Naming

The following is confusing:

```
PrimeFinder test;
PrimeFinderTest test;
```

You have both multiple `PrimeFinder` around which you named `test` as a `PrimeFinderTest` named `test`. In all cases the variable name is not descriptive and together it's confusing.

### Loops

Do you have a particular reason why the following is a `while` loop?

```
            while(j <= n) {
                if(j > n_) {
                    is_prime_[j] = false;
                }
                j += i;
            }
```

A `for` loop would be more readable here.

Now we're talking about that loop anyway, only use one letter variables like `i` and `j` when iterating (if at all, those extra bytes for full names won't bite you). Here, you're using both `n` and `n_` without documenting what they are. That's a maintainability trap.

There's no rule against trailing underscores (my personal preference is not to use them), but in this case the difference between `n` and `n_` is not distinctive enough. `n_ = n;` is also a good indication your naming could be improved.